# jQuery ajax request succeeding in console but callback isn't called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery POST request that looks something like this:

```
$.ajax("/myurl",{
    data:{
        ...
    },
    mimeType:"application/json",
    dataType:"application/json",
    method:"POST",
    success:function(r){
        console.log("success");
    },
    error:function(r){
        console.log("error");
        console.log(r);
    }
});
```

I turned on XHR logging in my chrome console, and it says the `XHR finished loading: POST http://localhost/myurl`. However, "error" is logged in my console as well, along with an XHR object:

```
error
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/myurl"
```

Why is it saying that the XHR finished loading, but at the same time there's an error? Why is there even an error? On the server-side, the server receives the request and sends a response.

Comment: The `error` callback receives three arguments. What are the values of the other two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that what the server is sending back isn't valid JSON, so although the ajax succeeds, parsing the JSON fails.

Your `dataType` is off, though, it should have one of these values: `"xml"`, `"json"`, `"script"`, or `"html"` — in your case, `"json"`. You also don't need (and probably don't want) to set `mimeType`.

Comment: I recall that removing `mimeType` actually made my code not work. I'll try though

Comment: @FireCubez - That's because your `dataType` is incorrect. If you fix it, and remove `mimeType`, the response will be treated as JSON. (All of this is a workaround, though; instead, the server should be sending back the correct `Content-Type` header: `application/json`.)

Comment: It is sending back `application/json`. Your answer solved it, i'll accept once I can

Comment: @FireCubez - Good deal! Then you can remove both `mimeType` and `dataType`. Happy coding!